# I get the following message in QuickOSM - cannot generate any layers

Tags: qgis-3, quickosm

I get the following message when downloading layers from quickOSM to qGIS. I am not familiar with code.

```
  File "C:\Users/Martin/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\base_processing_panel.py", line 47, in run
  self._run()
         
  File "C:\Users/Martin/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\quick_query_panel.py", line 421, in _run
  num_layers = process_quick_query(
 
  File "C:\Users/Martin/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\process.py", line 318, in process_quick_query
  return process_query(
 
  File "C:\Users/Martin/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\process.py", line 257, in process_query
  return open_file(
 
  File "C:\Users/Martin/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\process.py", line 106, in open_file
  layers = osm_parser.processing_parse()
 
  File "C:\Users/Martin/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\parser\osm_parser.py", line 147, in processing_parse
  validity = processing.run(
 
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 108, in run
  return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
 
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.5/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 169, in runAlgorithm
  raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing enough logs to help you. But it looks a common issue :

Go in your QGIS plugin manager, write `Processing` and check the plugin is **checked**.

[image]

If it doesn't help you, please provide more logs. From your QGIS log panel, the small comic strip bubble in the bottom right corner. Then you have different tabs.